# ¿Cómo mostrar un componente u otro basado en una condición?

Tags: angular6

Sucede que estoy trabajando en una vista y tengo un componente que llamo `modal`, además tengo dos enlaces en un `dropdown` que abren el mismo `modal` pero quiero que el cuerpo del modal cambie dependiendo del enlace al cual le dé clic; para esto tengo dos componentes más que son dos formularios `create-task` y `create-project` cada uno tiene campos distintos.  Lo que deseo hacer es cargar el componente correspondiente al enlace que clickee.

**HTML del dropdown que contiene los enlaces:**

```
<div class="dropdown-menu">
 <a class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#newModalShow" href="#"> New project </a>
 <a class="dropdown-item" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#newModalShow" href="#"> New task </a>
</div>
```

**HTML del modal:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="newModalShow" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="newModalShowLabel" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="newModalShowLabel"><i class="large material-icons">note</i> {{ titleModal }} </h5>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
   </div>
   <div class="modal-body">
    <app-form-new-project></app-form-new-project>
  <!-- <app-form-new-task></app-form-new-task> -->
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Y el formularios simplemente tiene algunos campos.

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar [Ngif](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf):

```
<div *ngIf="condition; then thenBlock else elseBlock"></div>
<ng-template #thenBlock>...</ng-template>
<ng-template #elseBlock>...</ng-template>
```